# Verify Microsoft exchange server status

Tags: service, exchange-server, monitoring

Can somebody help me, how to check whether the Microsoft exchange server is running/UP, in command line?
My objective is , just to monitor Microsoft exchange server is alive. Not the physical server.

Thank you
Luke

Answer (score 0):

you can test the server mentioned below commaund

```
Test-ServiceHealth
    [[-Server] <ServerIdParameter>]
    [-ActiveDirectoryTimeout <Int32>]
    [-Confirm]
    [-DomainController <Fqdn>]
    [-MonitoringContext <Boolean>]
    [-WhatIf]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

i hope answer the question

Answer (score 0):

additionally,

- you can monitor following url by using your monitoring application

> https://IPADDRESS/Autodiscover/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/ecp/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/EWS/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/mapi/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/OAB/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/owa/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/PowerShell/healthcheck.htm
> https://IPADDRESS/Rpc/healthcheck.htm

passively, you can check by using following scripts

[https://www.alitajran.com/exchange-server-health-check-powershell-script/"](https://www.alitajran.com/exchange-server-health-check-powershell-script/%22)

https://microsoft.github.io/CSS-Exchange/Diagnostics/HealthChecker/